# How to integrate these integrals from the free fall problem in classical mechanics?

Tags: integration, derivatives, classical-mechanics

How to integrate: $\int_{0}^{2}\dot x^2(t) dt$ and $\int_{0}^{2} 2\dot x(t)dt$?

I would be very grateful for any answers!

Comment: Set $\dot x=v$, then the free-fall equation is separable. Look into your integral tables for the suitable substitution and anti-derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the dot means derivatve.
The second one is
$$
\int_0^2 2 \dot{x}(t)\;dt = 2x(t)\bigg\vert_0^2 = 2x(2)-2x(0)
$$
The reason is:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\;x(t) = \dot{x}(t)
$$
so $x(t)$ is an anti-derivatvie of $\dot{x}(t)$.

For the first one here is no such simple evaluation.